# Rails 3 'where' with no conditions or 'all' lazy loading

Tags: lazy-loading, ruby-on-rails-3, where-clause

How can I get ActiveRecord::Relation object of the model without any conditions?
Of cause I can write

```
User.where # without any args
```

, but thats looks confusing

Answer (score 3):

`User.scoped` will do it. All methods like `where`, `order`, `limit`, etc. are delegated to `scoped`. Calling it directly gives you the bare `Relation`.